# Not able to run two instance of Authentication service with Zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am working with Eureka/Zuul and Springboot microservices.

While mapping multiple instances of same application to Zuul gateway, i am using serviceId attribute.

Here i had shared my application.yml of zuul project.

```
server:
  port: 8093
  servlet:
    context-path: /apigateway

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-proxy
   
zuul:
    sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
    host:
      socketTimeoutMillis: 60000
    routes:
        authenticator-oauth:
            path: /oauth/
            url: http://localhost:8092/authenticator/oauth
        sample-resource-server:
            path: /sample/
            serviceId: sample
            stripPrefix: false

sample:
   ribbon:
      NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
      listOfServers: http://localhost:8096,http://localhost:8097
      ConnectTimeout: 60000
      ReadTimeout: 60000
      MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
      MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100
            
authenticator:
  ribbon:
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
    listOfServers: http://localhost:8092, http://localhost:8091
    ConnectTimeout: 1000
    ReadTimeout: 5000
    MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
    MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100

       
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8094/eureka/  
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

I am able to run my authenticator application.

Also i am able to run my **`sample`** application on both port(**`8096/8097`**) with load balancing .

Here as you can see i had mapped authenticator service using URL and it's working fine.

**`url: http://localhost:8092/authenticator/oauth`**

But when i had mapped it with service id as below code, it's not able to redirect with actual authentication service url.

```
      authenticator-oauth:
      path: /authenticator/**
      serviceId: authenticator
      stripPrefix: false
```

In both these cases, i am hitting same URL as below

**`http://localhost:8093/apigateway/oauth/token`**.

Why **`authentication service`** or **`oauth/token`** end point behave differently compare to normal application?

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to register multiple instance of same micro-service you have to do nothing
in ZUUL API GATEWAY.
Add a property in the micro-service itself for which you are creating multiple instance.

```
server:  
  port: ${PORT:0}
eureka:  
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

1. Every time you will start same service it will start on unique port
2. It will register itself with eureka discovery service
3. Load Balancing will be done automatically since ribbon comes built in with Zuul